# Creating list of pdf files

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I have a list of parts. All parts have PDF files on the server. Now, I want to create a list of links to these files based on data from the model. The file location is \Server\Files\Pdf. In the model, there is a field called HeadPart, which appears as "PART-332-223-122". I simply need to add ".pdf" at the end of the link.

I wanted to do it this way, but I got error CS1061:

`<a href="\\Server\Files\Pdf\@item.HeadPart.pdf">@item.HeadPart</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what the language parser is being told here:

```
@item.HeadPart.pdf
```

You're looking for a property called `pdf` on the property `HeadPart` (which is presumably a string).  The error is telling you that no such property exists.

You can explicitly wrap the server-side expression:

```
href="\\Server\Files\Pdf\@(item.HeadPart).pdf"
```

This tells the parser that specifically `item.HeadPart` is Razor server-side code and the rest is client-side.

Comment: Yes, true. I knew it but i didn't know how to make it correctly. Thanks you.